# Git: How to create a new branch from an earlier/older commit in master branch?

Tags: git

I made three commits in the master branch: C1, C2 and C3.
From that point I made a new branch 'Branch1'. Did some 
changes and have them commited in C4 on Branch1.

Things would look as follows:

```
C1--C2--C3<--Master
         \     
          C4<--Branch1
```

However, now I want to use an earlier commit in the Master 
to fork off a new branch 'Branch2'. i.e. in the Master branch,
I want to go back in time at C2 and build on top of that in a 
new branch. The master branch is not to be disturbed in any way.
C5 is a commit saving changes done in the new 'Branch2'.
Graphically, the following figure should explain what i want:

```
      C5<--Branch2
     /
C1--C2--C3<--Master
         \     
          C4<--Branch1
```

1. What git command sequence(s) will take me there?
2. My second question is that after achieving the case in second
   figure, if a 'revert' is performed to remove C3 in Master branch, 
   What effect would it have on Branch1? Would code in Branch1 become 
   corrupted or unstable?

Answer (score 8):

simply check out that commit and specify a branch to create:

```
git checkout -b Branch2 C2
```

for your second question, that depends on how you define 'revert' (`git revert` or `git reset`). in both cases Branch1 will still contain the commit C3 (remember, in git branches are just 'pointers', ancestry information is stored in the commits themselves).