# Create a branch from a previous commit of master

Tags: git

So we have a master in our repo, we want to create a branch that was based on an earlier commit in that branch. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to create a new branch from an earlier/older commit in master branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546919/git-how-to-create-a-new-branch-from-an-earlier-older-commit-in-master-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+create+branch+early+commit

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the man of `git branch` you will see the following:

```
git branch [--track | --no-track] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

And:

```
       <start-point>
       The new branch head will point to this commit. It may be given as a branch name, a commit-id, or a tag. If this option is omitted, the current
       HEAD will be used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>
```